# Navigation with li and jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li class="quickHelp"><a href="" title="Ayuda Rápida"></a>
    <div>
        Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum vel, tempor at, varius non, purus. Mauris vitae nisl nec metus placerat consectetuer. Donec ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in consectetuer hendrerit, urna elit eleifend nunc, ut consectetuer nisl felis ac diam. Etiam non felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus egestas at sem. Mauris quam enim, molestie in, rhoncus ut, lobortis a, est.
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:9999;
}
ul#navigation li {
    width: 100px;
}
ul#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;    
    background-color:#CCC;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    border:1px solid #AFAFAF;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px #000;    
    opacity: 0.6;*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);
}
ul#navigation .quickHelp a{
    background-image: url(../Content/images/info/leftBanner.png);
    background-position: right;
}

ul#navigation div{
    position: absolute;
}​
```

**JS**

```
$('#navigation a').stop().animate({ 'marginLeft': '-275px' }, 1000);

$('#navigation > li').hover(
    function () {
        $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({ 'marginLeft': '-2px' }, 200);
    },
    function () {
        $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({ 'marginLeft': '-275px' }, 200);
    }
);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I want the content of the `<div>` to be displayed inside the `<li>` not below...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/j9ny8/) is a live example of it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The content of the div is inside your li, your link is just pushing it below it. Remember you're working with two block-level elements here.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that, you're right! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `div`, and you need to place the text inside the anchor `a`, because that is what you are using as the slide-out.

See the [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ny8/13/).

Comment: But I don't want it to be a link... and I need to add some styles to that `<div>`

Comment: @LuisSánchez: If you don't want the text to be underlined (which is not the same as the text being a link - the _whole thing_ is a link), the just add some styles. And if you need the `div`, go ahead and add it surrounding the `a`. I updated the JsFiddle.